# Adding Custom Elements to Item in RSS Feed

Tags: html, rss, element

I am a little confused about something regarding RSS Feeds.  I want to have several custom elements in each item tag, so that it looks like this:

```
<item>
  <title></title>
  <custom1></custom2>
  <link></link>
  <custom2></custom2>
</item>
```

I added:

```
<rss xmlns:custom1="" xmlns:custom2="">
```

at the top of it, but it still tells me it is an undefined item element.